# Skype lesson - voice and instrument into Skype

Tags: recording, mixing, lessons

I have a Mac and an irig hd, is there anyway I can capture my voice with the built in microphone as well as my bass guitar and feed that into Skype?

Comment: Have you looked into RogueAmoeba software?   They (at least used to) have tools for mixing all sorts of inputs and passing to all sorts of outputs.

Comment: What OS are you on? The answers are going to be highly dependent on that. For OSX, you could probably rig up an aggregate device or use SoundFlower, for Linux you could probably do it with JACK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per request:

I'd suggest reading through [Rogue Amoeba's](http://rogueamoeba.com/) catalog of audio software tools. In particular, Audio Hijack ought to be able to do the capture.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your OS, of course, but here are some options for each:

### Linux:

- use Jack and Pulse-audio, with the Pulseaudio Jack source/sink enabled. The easiest way to do that is to install `cadence` from [KXStudio](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications)
- When Skype audio is running, open `pavucontrol` (Pulse Audio Volume Control in the applications menu), and set skype to use the jack sink/source in the first and second tabs.
- You can now router it where ever you want, via JACK, the easiest option is via `catia` (also from KXstudio, and available in the 'tools' tab of cadence).

### OSX:

- You might get away with [creating an aggregate device](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202000), depending on your requirements
- If that doesn't work, you could try routing the audio with [Soundflower](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/)

### Windows:

- There is a [solution using Virtual Audio Cable](https://superuser.com/a/513802/48920)

Answer (score -3):

That sounds like a plan for delivering gourmet food samples through a ketchup pipeline.

Skype and built-in microphones are intended for speech transmission.  While today's bandwidths can deliver a lot more, I doubt that Skype is easily persuaded to cater for that, and built-in microphones just don't deliver here.  Apart from being bad to position for performance recording, they have rather constrained frequency response.

Comment: This is just plain wrong.  I'm one of many who have had music lessons over Skype Video, with quite sufficient bandwidth, thank you.

Comment: I use Skype regularly for video conversations, so, would say, depends. Sometimes the quality is really good enough for everything, sometimes it may be video freezes and problems with even speech understanding.

Comment: @h22: those are problems with your internet connection speed, not the software..